# How to find a non trivial solution for $Ax\leq0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

How can I check if $Ax\leq0$ has a non trivial solution, if it does how can I find one ?

**Note** By $\leq 0$, I mean that all entries of the vector $Ax$ are less than equal to $0$.

$A$ is a given $m \times n$ matrix (where $m > n$) and  $x$ is a $n \times 1$ vector of unknowns.

Comment: In general this needn't be possible (consider, say, a situation where $m=2,n=1$ and the two entries of $A$ have different sign). So you need *some* assumptions...

Comment: You are right, I have edited the question. I first need to determine if it has a non trivial solution.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo A is tall matrix, i.e m>n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First check for the nullity, if there is a non-zero $x$ such that $Ax=0$ then we are done.
- Otherwise, it means for $x \ne 0$, $Ax \ne 0$. We want to find $x \ne 0$ such that $Ax\le 0$. Let $v=Ax$, we want $v \le 0$ and $x \ne 0$. Also, let me control the magnitude of $v$ to restrict each entry to be between $-1$ and $0$. Let $e$ be the all one vector.
  $$\min_{v, x} e^Tv$$
  $$v=Ax$$
  $$ -e \le v \le 0 $$

which is a linear programming problem.

More compactly, we do not need to define $v$ explicitly,

$$\min_{ x} e^TAx$$

$$ -e \le Ax \le 0 $$

Comment: Just to confirm, if the minimum value I get is $0$ this means then there is no solution other than $x=0$. Also, in this LP problem formed the answer would always be finite and can never be -infinity because you restricted the magnitude of $v$. Right?

Comment: good point, ok, check nullity if you get $0$ as the solution in order to get a non-trivial solution. I purposely bound it so get in the worst case, $v$ can only take $-n$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)